# Combine two cells in Excel based on contents of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can't seem to find any equivalent question on Superuser, so here goes.

In excel, I have used "Text to Columns" for Delimited data, separating by Tab or Space. The problem is one column is a name that separates first and last with a comma. This has now been separated into two columns.

I'd like to join these two columns (A:B), but since they also contain non-name data, I need to specify only joining cells where "A" contains a comma to only affect the related cells.

Comment: So, you have mixed data in the column. What kind of "non-name" data is in the cells? Is it also text? What have you tried?

Comment: @CharlieRB Text, numbers, etc. A variety of content, but none of which includes a comma unless it's the last name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a new column, you can use this formula to `FIND` the comma. If the comma exists (no `ISERROR`), the names will be combined (`CONCATENATE`). If there is no comma (`ISERROR`), nothing will be returned (`" "`).

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1, 1)), "", CONCATENATE(A1, " ",B1))
```

[image]